# params[key].instance_eval Ruby explanation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reviewing a Ruby gem called Mailboxer which allows you to implement a simple private messaging system in a Rails app. There's a sample app on Github that I don't fully understand. In the controller ([click here](https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app/blob/master/app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb)) the author uses the following actions:

```
  def conversation_params(*keys)
    fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)
  end

  def message_params(*keys)
    fetch_params(:message, *keys)
  end

  def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
    params[key].instance_eval do
      case subkeys.size
      when 0 then self
      when 1 then self[subkeys.first]
      else subkeys.map{|k| self[k] }
      end
    end
  end
```

I think the first question I have is what exactly is that fetch_params action doing? I researched this a little bit and it seems like this is getting the id from the URL (via GET method) but why? I would greatly appreciate an explanation as I am unfamiliar with this subject. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain, how does it work, but it's a bit tricky.

`fetch_params(key, *subkeys)` method takes a hash from the params specified by the `key` parameter (:conversation or :message), and gets information from it for attributes specified by `subkeys` parameter:

- if there are no subkeys passed, then it will just return plain params[key] (e.g. `fetch_params(:conversation) == params[:conversation]`
- if there is only one element passed, then it will just return it's value (e.g. `fetch_params(:message, :body) == params[:message][:body]`
- if there are multiple subkeys passed, it will return value for each subkey (e.g. `fetch_params(:conversation, :body, :subject) == (params[:conversation][:body], params[:conversation][:subject])`

Basically, `*` before last parameter tells ruby to pack all corresponding attributes into one parameter, e.g. `fetch_params(:message, :one, :two, :three) => subkeys == [:one, :two, :three]`.

Then you add `*` before an array, ruby will expand your array into multiple arguments, e.g. `*[:one, :two, :three] == :one, :two, :three`.

Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to write this out! This definitely helps a great deal. Now, I know you aren't the author of the linked Github project, but couldn't you just pass the entire :conversation param and any associated values? Why separate this out?